# What is the difference between teams.live.com and teams.microsoft.com?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When I create a meeting link from my team's app, I get the URL similar to **teams.live.com**, but when people share the link with me, sometimes I see it as **teams.microsoft.com** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft introduced Teams for personal accounts some time ago.
Business accounts are `teams.microsoft.com`, personal accounts are `teams.live.com`

Same as for Hotmail/outlook (x.live.com) vs outlook.office.com